# Write the pointer in the pointer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have variable

```
int v1, v2;
```

I have two pointers:

```
int *ptr1, *ptr2;
```

and an array of pointers

```
int *array[2] = {ptr1, ptr2};
```

It is possible to change the ptr1 using pointer array to do operation like `ptr1 = &v2`

`array[0] = &v1;` (I know this record is wrong, but I mean the idea of writing new value into the ptr1 pointer)

Comment: No, it's not possible because array stores *copy* of pointer. To do so store pointer to pointer. ```int * ptr1 = &v1; int **arr[] = {&ptr1}; *arr[0] = &v2;```

Comment: @user7408320 Which language? C? C++?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it with a `int* []` (array of pointer), because the element of `array` is just a copy, then any modification on the element has nothing to do with the original pointer. So `array[0] = &v1;` won't change `ptr1`.

You can use a `int** []` (array of pointer to pointer) instead, e.g.

```
int **array[2] = {&ptr1, &ptr2};
```

then

```
*array[0] = &v1;  // this will make ptr1 point to v1
```